# detect and merge by label

Tags: python, tableau-api

I have a dataset that has 500 000 rows, and 2 columns. Both columns have emails in them.

1 row will always have two emails, and email in column one is 'linked' with email in column 2.

Now, I have a separate dataset that links each email with an ID (separately), approx 30 000 IDs assigned to emails.

I am trying to find a tool / solution that will allow to assign each email within a dataset (the one that has two columns, with total of 500 000 entries) with an ID that is available In the second file, with logic that ID is a Label, and should be assigned to each email.

Maybe someone knows about some merging tactic I could use?

Comment: put screenshot of sample dataset

Comment: sample data would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

If each email has a unique ID, then you need to do this aggregation in steps:
Assume:
- dataset1: 500,00 rows with 2 cols contain emails: email1, email2
- dataset2: 30,000  rows with 2 cols: ID and email

1. separate the `dataset1` into two: `dataset1.1` with a single col: `email1` and `dataset1.2` with a single col: `email2`.
2. left join `dataset1.1` with `dataset2`: resulting 2 cols `email1` and `ID1`
3. left join `dataset1.2` with `dataset2` : resulting 2 cols `email2` and `ID2`
4. concatenate the resulting `dataset1.1` and `dataset1.2` as follows:

> ```
> import pandas as pd
>
> # after left join 1st col with IDs
> dataset1_1 = pd.DataFrame([["lulu@gmail.com", "31"], ["Dudu@gmail.com", "26"]],
>                   columns=['email', 'id'])
> print(dataset1_1)
> # after left join 2nd col with IDs
> dataset1_2 = pd.DataFrame([["lulu@xyz.com", "32"], ["Dudu@xyz.com", "27"]],
>                   columns=['email', 'id'])
> print(dataset1_2)
>
> # now merge both 
> pd.concat([dataset1_1, dataset1_2], ignore_index=True)
> ```

The result will be as follows:

[image: result]

Hope this will help!